# Generated view filled with NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, view, phpmyadmin

**Update:** The problem seems to be fixed, it occurred due to me using different lowercase instead of caps while declaring. However, I am now facing an issue where the view "vw_formdatahard" is just filled with multiple "NULL". I'm going crazy here.

I have a procedure which will create views based on available data in a Wordpress & Buddypress database. This runs just fine on my local Mamp server but gives me an error whenever I call the procedure on my hosted server. Even when I copy the entire DB from my local server to the online server, it stil returns the error. I'm no mysql hero so I'm going off the deep end here.. Why won't this run?

> The following query has failed: "CALL `stp_FormQueryBuilder`();
>   MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'd.user_id' in 'field list'

```
BEGIN 


DECLARE sqlText text;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_FormDataRows;

CREATE VIEW vw_FormDataRows AS
SELECT d.user_id, f.name, 
CASE WHEN left(f.name, 4) = 'FOTO' && LEFT(d.value, 9) = '/profiles' THEN CONCAT("/wp-content/uploads",d.value)
ELSE d.value END AS 'value'


        FROM wp_bp_xprofile_fields AS F 
        LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data AS D ON F.id = D.field_id
        WHERE 
            parent_id = 0 
            AND group_id = 1
            AND d.user_id IN(SELECT U.user_id FROM wp_usermeta AS U WHERE U.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' AND U.meta_value = '0')

ORDER BY d.user_id, f.id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 (SELECT b.user_id, b.name, b.value
FROM (SELECT d.user_id, f.name, d.value
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_fields AS F 
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data AS D ON F.id = D.field_id
WHERE 
    parent_id = 0 
    AND group_id = 1
            AND d.user_id IN(SELECT U.user_id FROM wp_usermeta AS U WHERE U.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' AND U.meta_value = '0')
ORDER BY d.user_id, f.id ) AS B);


SET @sql = NULL;

SET group_concat_max_len = 4096;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN name = ', name,
                ' THEN value END) AS `', replace(name, ' ','_'), '`'))
  INTO sqlText
  FROM temp1;


DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_FormDataHard;

SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW vw_FormDataHard AS SELECT user_id, ', sqlText, ' 
                     FROM vw_FormDataRows 
                    GROUP BY user_id');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;

END
```

Comment: Just a note, your left joins execute as regular inner joins, since you have right side table conditions in the where clauses.

Comment: change to D.user_id

Comment: Maybe because the table alias is `D` and you use `d` to select

Comment: @Bert you were absolutely right. Silly mistake on my end but thank you nonetheless!

Comment: Just wondering though, how come this would work on one but not on the other?

Comment: @Rutger_ADD I guess your local machine is Windows and the server runs Linux? This makes a difference in case-sensitivity.

Comment: @Bert, do you mean MySQL is sometimes case-sensitive and sometimes not (when it comes to identifiers), depending on platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined the alias `d` just `D` and these are different, because aliases are case sensitive.

Comment: That was it.. I've been staring myself blind at this!

Answer (score 0):

You Declare **Capital letter "D"** and use **Small letter "d"**
so,Change it any one